# Authentication Failure when submitting Authorization Code in OAuth Web-Server Flow

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, oauth

I am trying to test the Webserver OAuth as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)

I can get the authorization code successfully by opening https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=(xxxxxx)
&redirect_uri=https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback. This results in the Code after the authorization is complete

Now comes the problem, for some reason when i try to use the 'code' for the POST request to the https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token, i am getting `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}` even though all parameters are correct. I have also relaxed all IP restrictions.

I was reading this, but again my endpoint is correct since this is a DE org and all parameters look ok, am i missing anything. Attaching screenshot for reference,[image]

Comment: Do you have my domain set on your dev org?

Comment: is your callback url in your connected App same as that you are sending in request?

Comment: Yes @PranayJaiswal - callback url is same as the sending request, otherwise it will give the error {"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description":"redirect_uri must match configuration"}

Comment: Can i ask where do you get the code value from. Im don't have any ideas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you copying your authorization code from browser redirect? Its getting URL encoded and hence its saying invalid authorization code.

Check if your auth code is ending with "%3D%3D" replace that with "==" .

This solved my problem plenty of times.

Comment: this solved my problem, thanks a lot pranay. Yes it was indeed the == issue at the end, i had missed that one and that caused the issue. Thanks a lot guys for all ur inputs :)

Comment: Hello, i don't know where to get the code value from. Is it the initial access token?